# Update Ubuntu terminal on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am new to Ubuntu. I have Ubuntu 14 terminal installed on my Windows 10 laptop. I want to get Ubuntu 16 or 18. When I tried to uninstall the current Ubuntu 14 terminal, I couldn't find it in **Programs and Features** inside **Control Panel**. Or I can choose to update the current terminal, but I'm not sure how. Can anyone help please? Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can install other versions of Ubuntu to your Windows 10 through the Windows App Store. It is a free install.

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1804/9n9tngvndl3q) allows one to use Ubuntu Terminal and run Ubuntu command line utilities including bash, ssh, git, apt and many more. Ubuntu 18.04 WSL is published by Canonical. WSL2 which features a true Linux kernel can be installed in Windows 10 version 2004 and later.

**Please note that Windows 10 S does not support running this app.** *Windows 10 in S Mode can’t use command-line shells like PowerShell, Command Prompt, or Bash which are commonly used in WSL. Various other developer tools are also off limits.*<sup>**[*](https://www.howtogeek.com/354057/what-is-windows-10-in-s-mode/)**</sup>

---

#### Install the Windows Subsystem for Linux

1. To use this feature, one first needs to use *Turn Windows features on or off* and select *Windows Subsystem for Linux*, click *OK*, reboot, and use this app. This step can also be performed using Administrator PowerShell prompt:

   ```
    Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux"
   ```
2. Restart your computer when prompted.

#### Install Ubuntu 18.04

1. Check that Windows 10 build 16215 or later is installed.
2. Open the Microsoft Store and choose Ubuntu.
3. From the Ubuntu page, click the blue *Get* button.

---

To launch Ubuntu, type `ubuntu1804` on the command-line prompt (cmd.exe), or click on the Ubuntu tile in the Start Menu.

Comment: Please note that Windows 10 S does not support running this app.